# Disk failure in LVM partition: How to access the data in remaining area

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, lvm

I have an LVM volume with 6 disks. One of the drives died and I don't know what to do to access the data on the other disks. I am not interested in the data on the failed disk.

I first activated partial LVM.

`vgchange -a y --activationmode partial myVG`

I then tried to mount the activated partial LVM but no luck because the system can't read superblock.
I attempted to find back-up superblocks with dumpe2fs command but it said:

> couldn't find valid filesystem superblock

`mkfs.ext4 -n LVpath` gave me a list of back-up superblocks, but none of them worked with `mount -o sb=xxxxxx LVpath /mountpoint`

As suggested in here https://serverfault.com/questions/319427/how-to-remove-bad-disk-from-lvm2-with-the-less-data-loss-on-other-pvs

I performed `vgreduce --removemissing --force myVG`. This removed the original LVM group and wondering how to access the data inside the reduced VG group. Can I simply create a new LVM partition on that? I am not sure it won't wipe out any data in remaining disks. I really appreciate it if anyone can help out.

Comment: Was it one huge LV spanning all the disks? Usually the partial recovery refers to LVs not located on the missing disk... recovering a filesystem that has a full disk worth of data missing is a challenge since it usually affects all files directories, metadata, etc. so the damage is more extensive than just files that were actually located on that drive

Comment: Yes, it is one LV spanning all the disk... :( Is there any way to check whatever is remaining without fully wiping drives? (maybe it's not even possible?) Thanks @frostschutz!